# Can $\,9\!\cdot\!10^n+4\,$ be a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

I think $\,9\!\cdot\!10^n+4\,$ can be a perfect square, since it is $0 \pmod 4$ (a quadratic residue modulo $4$), and $1 \pmod 3$ (also a quadratic residue modulo  $3$).
But when I tried to find if $\;9\!\cdot\!10^n+4\,$ is a perfect square, I didn’t succeed. Can someone help me see if $\;9\!\cdot\!10^n+4\,$ can be a perfect square ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: I suggest:  if $n=2k+1$ it looks like the square root is *very* close, but not equal to,  to $9.5\times 10^k$.  Start there. (Note:  the problem is easy is $n$ is even.  Why?)

Comment: For $n\le 10^5$ , this expression is not a perfect power , let alone a perfect square.

Comment: I did some work and it boiled down to where or not there exists positive integers $n$, $m$, st $10m^2+1=n^2$

Comment: @JustWandering  Well, that's a standard Pell's equation.  $(m,n)=(6,19)$ is a solution, for instance (there are infinitely many).  Can you use that to address the OP's question?

Comment: In case there was a solution, you could use same approach as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926124). It still works to show there is no solution but of course inspecting $\bmod 11$ is simpler in this case.

Comment: @lulu, how have you found that solution ? Actually, there does not exist any solution.

Comment: @Angelo The solution is to the Pell's equation $10m^2+1=n^2$, not to the original question.

Comment: @Angelo  I solved the Pell equation, not the original equation.  Personally, I see no connection between the problems but the user JustWondering claimed that solving the Pell equation was equivalent to the OP's question.  If there actually was a connection, I was hoping that user would reveal it.

Comment: @lulu, I agree with you, in fact the original equation and the Pell’s one are not equivalent.

Comment: **Dupe** of  [Prove nonsquare $111...161 = (10^k-1)/9+50$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542121/prove-nonsquare-111-161-10k-1-950). You chose the wrong modulus to test. See [this Hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542121/prove-111-161-is-not-a-square#comment9750383_2542121) in the dupe for how to choose it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that if $$9\!\cdot\!10^n+4=m^2\implies (m+2)(m-2)=9\!\cdot\!10^n$$

Note that $5^n$ must divide either $m+2$ or $m-2$.
If that happens, the rest of the factors are not big enough to maintain the difference of $4$ as $\left|5^n-9\!\cdot\!2^n\right|>4$ for $n\geqslant3$.

Answer (score 17):

If you reduce mod $11$ you get $(-2)(-1)^n+4 \equiv 2$ or $6 \pmod{11}$.  Neither $2$ nor $6$ is a quadratic residue mod $11$.

Comment: Wow, a nice solution ! (+1)

Comment: Congratulations ! I like your solution very much.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $9\cdot10^n+4\equiv4$ is a perfect square.
$9\cdot10^n+4\equiv4\pmod9$, so $9\cdot10^n+4$ can be represented as $(9m-2)^2=81m^2-18m+4$ or $(9m+2)^2=81m^2+18m+4$, where $m\in\mathbb{N}$.
If $9\cdot10^n+4=81m^2-18m+4$, $$10^n=9m^2-2m=m(9m-2)$$
This means that $m$ and $9m-2$ must be powers of $10$.
Clearly, $9m-2>m$ because $m>0$. If $m≠1$, $m\equiv0\pmod{10}$,  but then $9m-2\equiv8\pmod{10}$, which doesn't work. If $m=1$, $9m-2=7$, which also doesn't work.
If $9\cdot10^n+4=81m^2+18m+4$, $$10^n=9m^2+2m=m(9m-2)$$
This means that $m$ and $9m+2$ must be powers of $10$.
Clearly, $9m+2>m$ because $m>0$. If $m≠1$, $m\equiv0\pmod{10}$,  but then $9m+2\equiv2\pmod{10}$, which doesn't work. If $m=1$, $9m+2=11$, which also doesn't work.
Therefore, there is a contradiction and so $9\cdot10^n+4$ cannot be a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

Lets try construction such a number. Suppose we have:

$k^2-9\times 10^n=4$

We use following known Pell's equation:

$x^2-Dy^1=1$

For $D=10$ we have $x=19$ and $y=6$ such that:

$19^2-10\times 6^2=1$

multiplying both sides by $2^2$ we get"

$38^2-10\times 12^2=4$

we rewrite this as:

$38^2-9\times(4^2\times 10)=4$

multiplying both sides by $25^2$ we get:

$(25\times 38)^2-9\times 10^5=4\times 25^2=2500=2496+4$

Or:

$[(25\times 38)^2-2496]-9\times 10^5=4$

Or generally:

$A=[(25\times 38)\times 10^m-(25\times 10^{2m}+96)]$

here in equation $k^2-9\times 10^n=4$, $n=2m+1$

$A$ must be perfect square.May be by brute force we can find such a number.