# Can $300$…$04$ be a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

$300…04$ is divisible by $4$ and always $1$ mod $3$. Sometimes, $300$…$04$ is $1$ mod $11$, which is a quadratic residue modulo $11$. But when I tried to check if there is any perfect square form of $300$…$04$, I didn’t succeed. Can $300$…$04$ be a perfect square?

Comment: I just verified with Python that for every prime p < 100, there exist a number of this form that is a square mod p.

Comment: p: smallest n such that 3*10^n+4 is a quadratic residue mod p.
3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 3, 11: 1, 13: 3, 17: 2, 19: 7, 23: 4, 29: 1, 31: 2, 37: 1, 41: 4, 43: 5, 47: 1, 53: 3, 59: 2, 61: 1, 67: 2, 71: 2, 73: 2, 79: 2, 83: 3, 89: 1, 97: 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can $\,9\!\cdot\!10^n+4\,$ be a perfect square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622956/can-9-cdot-10n4-be-a-perfect-square) - found in the RHS Related list. Note this [answer](/a/4622986) there uses basically the same technique as in my now deleted [answer](/a/4623890), i.e., if the square is $x^2$, then $5^k$ must divide $x-2$ or $x+2$, but this then means the product, i.e., $x^2-4$, will be too large.

Comment: @BillDubuque FYI, this problem can be solved relatively easily using a size argument, as I explain in the comment above re: a proposed duplicate, and in my now deleted answer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Agreed, I hadn't had a chance to look closely (other than a brief glance at the comments). Good work.